# Can you change canvas style parameters multiple times between draw calls?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to draw lots of rectangles with different stroke and fill colors. When working on proof of concept, I drew them all in a single context.stroke + context.fill call for a B/W representation. Now I need to make them all colorful and am stroking/filling them one by one and its making things slow down quite a bit. Is there a way to still do it in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, any context.stroke()/context.fill() will only use the latest strokeStyle/fillStyle that's set at the time of the stroke/fill call.  So you only get 1 color choice per stroke()/fill().

And yes, changing context state (like strokeStyle/fillStyle) is relatively costly in terms of performance.  If many of your colorful objects have the same color, you will gain performance by drawing all the same colored objects at the same time. (Draw all the red objects, then draw all the blue objects, etc.)